# Notepad save button messed up line returns

Tags: windows, notepad

In notepad when I have a large file open, when I press save EVERY line feed is deleted and all compressed! Any suggestions?

Comment: That doesn't sound likely. What kind of file is it? Where did this file come from?

Comment: Downloaded from a filezilla FTP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had used a registry hack to enable the status bar AND word wrap at the same time, which bugged it. Disabling the hack fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Choose `File`, `Save As` and note the encoding.

Use a Hex Dump tool to check the line endings - notepad expects CR LF but files from non-Windows sources, or files downloaded with incorrect FTP settings might have just CR or just LF.

Open the file in Wordpad instead.

Comment: Noooo!  Wordpad is EVIL!  It pretends to know vanilla ascii but prefers the RTF and DOC formats.  Well, I suppose you could use Wordpad if you promise never to put the resultant file on the web.  A better solution would involve obtaining one of the wonderful Windows based Notepad replacements (Notepad++,Notepad2, etc...)  (Trying to be nice, I'm not a Windows user.)